# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.monitoring_v3.types' has no attribute 'MetricDescriptor'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, monitoring

I am running a script to create gpu metrics on gcp and getting the following errors:

```bash
AttributeError: 'MetricServiceClient' object has no attribute 'project_path'

AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.monitoring_v3.types' has no attribute 'MetricDescriptor'
```

Answer (score 6):

#### project_path

The 2.0 release of the `google-cloud-monitoring` library included a [breaking change](https://github.com/googleapis/python-monitoring/pull/54) that wasn't documented in the change log, but it is covered in the [upgrading guide](https://github.com/googleapis/python-monitoring/blob/d25e49f13e6f880e77fcb0dc5ef4e3c61fba079a/UPGRADING.md#project-path-helper-method). The `project_path` function was renamed to `common_project_path`.

`Versions < 2.0.0`

```py
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_path = client.project_path("project_id")
```

`Versions >= 2.0.0`

```py
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_path = client.common_project_path("project_id")
```

#### MetricDescriptor

The MetricDescriptor type looks to have moved around in the `2.0.0` release as well. It's also covered in the [upgrading guide](https://github.com/googleapis/python-monitoring/blob/d25e49f13e6f880e77fcb0dc5ef4e3c61fba079a/UPGRADING.md#more-details) (with an incomplete snippet).

`Versions < 2.0.0`

```py
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3

descriptor = monitoring_v3.types.MetricDescriptor()
```

`Versions >= 2.0.0`

```py
from google.api import metric_pb2 as ga_metric

descriptor = ga_metric.MetricDescriptor()
```